# The diagram shows 80" on the inside, with 4"x4" posts, why does it show 90" on the outside?

Tags: pergola

I'm trying to understand the instructions for this pergola, but to me, there's a 2" discrepancy...

[image]

The diagram shows 80" on the inside, with 4"x4" posts, so why does it show 90" on the outside? Shouldn't it be 88" on the outside?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I should actually be 87" - planed 4x4s are 3.5", not 4".

Comment: Well, it's pretty simple. Either the diagram is wrong, or the posts are actually 5" wide.

Comment: Are they 4x4s or 6x6s? I guess either way it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I couldn't find your exact pergola at newenglandarbors.com, but similar ones did specify a 5" post. So the numbers might be right.

In any case, lay the parts out on the ground. The "bent" that's made up of two posts and the beam that sits between them will probably have a natural way that it goes together. Measure that width and set your base brackets accordingly.

Comment: True, sometimes when an issue arises like this, pre-assemble the frame, take the measure at the top where the joints come together and go from there. Sometimes the assembly instructions are good for intent and details, other than the discrepancy that the OP has picked up on...